# Accessing encoded query params in Angular using activatedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have angular application which is loaded after redirecting from another application. I want to access query params when authentication website returns to my Angular application. The url looks like

**http://localhost:4200/#/starterview?openId%3Dhttps:%2F%2Fmy.fidesque.net%2Fopenid%2Fyobtest_smeuser%26email%3Dyobtest@gml.nl%26userAuthMode%3DSP=**

I want to access the query params but I am not able to do it correctly using  `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` 
I suspect that it is due to encoded params. Is there any workaround ?

regards,
Venky

Comment: What does "I am not able to do it correctly" mean? What is your code, what do you expect it to do and what does it do instead? Why does the website uses such a horrible parameter name, without any value?

Comment: Same problem here, Angular cannot retrieve my query params. Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode the encoded URL using decodeURIComponent as answered by Venky. If you know the query params and want to extract the value from decoded URL. Use this function:

```
getQueryParamFromMalformedURL(name) {
    const results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(decodeURIComponent(this.router.url)); // or window.location.href
    if (!results) {
        return 0;
    }
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

If the url is http://localhost:4200/login?username=jerry&code=1234, then

```
this.getQueryParamFromMalformedURL('username'); // should return 'jerry'
```

Answer (score 2):

I decoded the URL using following code. Then I could extract the params correctly

```
const encodedUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/#/starterview?openId%3Dhttps:%2F%2Fmy.fidesque.net%2Fopenid%2Fyobtest_smeuser%26email%3Dyobtest@gml.nl%26userAuthMode%3DSP='
const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(encodedUrl);
console.log(decodedUrl);
```